# Calculated Column Based on Condition in Other Table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have to create a calculated column in a query (T2) based in a corresponding record in other table(T1) that attends to a certain condition, like this:

**T1** - Contracts:
   [T1.Id]
   [T1.Conclusion]

**T2** - Financial Entries:
   [T2.Id]
   [T2.ContractId]
   [**CALCULATED COLUMN** returning "ok" if a record exists in T1 where ([T1.Id]=[T2.ContractId] and [T1.Conclusion] <= TODAY)]

Thank´s!

Comment: share sample data of both tables and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery and `EXISTS` in a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT t2.id,
       t2.contractid,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM t1
                             WHERE t1.id = t2.contractid
                                   AND t1.conclusion <= curdate()) THEN
           'ok'
       END
       FROM t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with simple LEFT join using below Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.*, T1.id
FROM T2
LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.Id = T2.ContractId AND T1.Conclusion <= TODAY
```

If you get NULL in T1.id then not data exists else "OK".